# How to use multiple ReactPixel.track('abc') inside one component?

Tags: reactjs, facebook-pixel

I have a component on which I have to add two ReactPixel.track('abc') and 
ReactPixel.track('cba'), how can I achieve this? Do I need to add just one ReactPixe.init('id') or two? Here is a code example:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const options = {
    autoConfig: false,
  };



  ReactPixel.init('123123', options);
  ReactPixel.pageView();
  ReactPixel.track('abc');
  ReactPixel.track('cba');

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add multiple React inits on every page.
Just add it on your App.js(If you use create-react-app).
* You should initiate before you use it.

```
ReactPixel.init('123123', options);
```

If you need to get pageview details of whole app you need to use the below code.function in entry level.(I prefer after the init function)

```
ReactPixel.pageView();
```

There is no magic. It just call the same function that Facebook has given to you. `fbq('track', 'PageView');`

You can use track codes inside your functions. As a example after registration is successful you can create this track code.

```
ReactPixel.track('abc',{#data object goes here});
```

This is the example that Facebook has given.

```
fbq('track', 'Purchase',
  // begin parameter object data
  {
    value: 115.00,
    currency: 'USD',
    contents: [
      {
        id: '301',
        quantity: 1,
        item_price: 85.00
      },
      {
        id: '401',
        quantity: 2,
        item_price: 15.00
      }],
    content_type: 'product'
  }
  // end parameter object data
);
```

You can use this same function with `react-facebook-pixel` wrapper like this.

```
ReactPixel.track('abc',{#data object goes here});
```

**Tracking Custom Events**

> You can track custom events by calling the pixel's fbq('trackCustom') function, with your custom event name and (optionally) a JSON object as its parameters. Just like standard events, you can call the fbq('trackCustom') function anywhere between your webpage's opening and closing  tags, either when your page loads, or when a visitor performs an action like clicking a button.
>
> For example, let's say you wanted to track visitors who share a promotion in order to get a discount. You could track them using a custom event like this:

```
fbq('trackCustom', 'ShareDiscount', {promotion: 'share_discount_10%'});
```

you can track custom events with react wrapper like this

```
ReactPixel.trackCustom(#title_of_event,#data_object);
```

If you need more understanding of what this `react-facebook-pixel` has done. You can read the code of the package.
https://github.com/zsajjad/react-facebook-pixel/blob/master/src/index.js

Facebook documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/implementation/conversion-tracking#advanced_match